# Ember.js Handlebars scoping issue

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm having a scoping issue with Handlebars templates. I have a list of modules, each of which contains a list of services. So I have a template like this (with some markup removed):

```
{{#each controller}}
    <a onclick='$(".{{unbound uuid}}").toggle(0);'>

    {{#each service in services}}
        <div class='{{unbound uuid}}'></div>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that the second `{{unbound uuid}}` doesn't get substituted. And if I try accessing any other item of the outer scope, the same thing happens. However, the Ember.js site says that using the `each ... in` helper should preserve outer scope. What am I doing wrong?

(FYI: Using latest version of Ember.js, Ember-data and Handlebars.)

Comment: This blog post (http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/06/bind-and-bindattr.html) explains why you need to use `{{bindAttr}}` instead of normal handlebars `{{...}}`.

Comment: That's not really my issue. Using the `unbound` keyword takes care of that nicely (since I don't really need a binding there). My issue is with scope. And as you can see in my comment to Gevious' answer, it still doesn't make the correct substitution for `uuid`.

Comment: try to log your `uuid` in the inner scope, like `{{#each service in services}}{{log uuid}}{{/each}}` do you see the logged `uuid` in the console?

Comment: I have found a workaround. By wrapping the inner each with `{{#with uuid as outerUUID}} ... {{/with}}`, I can solve my problem. However, this doesn't explain why the scoping doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @intuitivepixel It prints out `undefined`, as I expected.

Comment: sorry, and what yields `{{log service.uuid}}`?

Comment: That also logs `undefined`.

Comment: is your `uuid` defined in the outer scoped items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the right syntax?

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  <a onclick='$(".{{unbound item.uuid}}").toggle(0);'>

  {{#each service in services}}
    <div class='{{unbound item.uuid}}'></div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This also works, which leads me to believe that scope is different when using the `controller` variable. That should probably be made a little bit more clear in the Ember.js documentation. Either way, thank you. Glad to have that solved.